# WPF custom ContentControl with Background Color based on Enum value

Tags: c#, wpf, enums, custom-controls

I'm trying to build a custom ContentControl with a State that should cause background color to change.

Therefore I defined the following Enum:

```
public enum OrderSourceState
{
    Idle,
    Busy,
}
```

And a DependencyProperty in my customControl class:

```
public class BorderWithState : ContentControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OrderStateProperty =
 DependencyProperty.Register("OrderState", typeof(OrderSourceState),
 typeof(BorderWithState), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OrderSourceState.Idle));

    // .NET Property wrapper
    public OrderSourceState OrderState
    {
        get { return (OrderSourceState)GetValue(OrderStateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OrderStateProperty, value); }
    }

    static BorderWithState()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(BorderWithState), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(BorderWithState)));
    }
}
```

And finally I defined the following XAML-Template:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MasterEKanBan"
xmlns:customControls="clr-namespace:MasterEKanBan.WPF">

<Style TargetType="{x:Type customControls:BorderWithState}">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="LightGray"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type customControls:BorderWithState}">
                <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding OrderState}" Value="{x:Static local:OrderSourceState.Idle}">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="LightGray"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>

                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding OrderState}" Value="{x:Static local:OrderSourceState.Busy}">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="LightGreen"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In the end I embed the custom Control by:

```
<customControls:BorderWithState Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="20"  OrderState="{x:Static local:OrderSourceState.Busy}" >
<Label Content="Mobile-RFID" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="30"/>
</customControls:BorderWithState>
```

But the color still remains gray.Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your triggers are wrong, namely you use `DataTrigger` with `Binding="{Binding OrderState}"`, which tries to find an `OrderState` property on the current `DataContext` and bind to it. What you want is to base the trigger on the property value on the templated control. In order to do that you should use regular `Trigger` with corresponding `Property` value:

```
<Trigger Property="OrderState" Value="(...)">
    (...)
</Trigger>
```

Or, at least specify proper source for the `DataTrigger` binding:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding OrderState, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="(...)">
    (...)
</DataTrigger>
```